# Why does Rudin say $V_\alpha \subset G_\alpha$?

Tags: real-analysis

I have some confusion about something in Baby Rudin.

My doubt is marked below in the red box.

[image]

**My  doubt:** Why does Rudin say that $V_\alpha \subset G_\alpha$?

My attempt:  Here  both $V_\alpha$  and $G_\alpha$  are open covers of $K$. So it must be that $V_\alpha = G_\alpha$.

Both $V_\alpha$ and $G_\alpha$ are open covers that contain finite subcovers.  Why do we not have $V_\alpha = G_\alpha$?

Comment: I edited your post a little bit; if it is not what you had in mind, please feel free to revert back or make changes as you see fit! Another thing to keep in mind is that I believe Rudin uses the symbol $\subset$ to mean $\subseteq$, so Rudin is not explicitly precluding the possibility that $V_\alpha = G_\alpha$. In fact, one could imagine cases where $V_\alpha = G_\alpha$, but your question does get at the fact that in general, the best we can say is that $V_\alpha$ is a subset of $G_\alpha$.

Comment: thanks  dear @AlexOrtiz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe an example will help illustrate. Imagine the $x$-axis $Y = \mathbb R\times\{0\}$ inside $X = \mathbb R^2$. The interval $K = [0,1]\times\{0\}$ inside $Y$ is compact relative to $Y$. The interval $K$ can be covered by sets of the form $G_\alpha$, where for every $\alpha$, $G_\alpha$ is an open ball in $\mathbb R^2$. Then put $V_\alpha = Y\cap G_\alpha$. The $V_\alpha$ are all open intervals contained in the $x$-axis $Y$, so they are not themselves equal to the balls $G_\alpha$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in that portion of the proof Rudin defines $\lbrace G_{\alpha}\rbrace \subset X$ as an open cover of $K$, and defines $V_{\alpha} = G_{\alpha}\cap Y$.  Then, since $V_{\alpha}$ is only the part of $G_{\alpha}$ that is also in $Y$, we can't conclude that $V_{\alpha} = G_{\alpha}$, but we can conclude that $V_{\alpha}\subset G_{\alpha}$.